# Web service function throwing exception while running application in release mode in VS

Tags: .net, web-services, exception

I am getting a  error while I am trying to execute a function provided by a webservice. While I am running the tool in VS in debug mode the function is returning the desired values, but if I am trying to run the application in the Release mode the function is throwing following exception.

Message : `There is an error in XML document (1, 1064).`

Stack Trace :

```
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Please suggest anything which I can try here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to trace your web service's call with this tool :

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/microsoft-soap-trace-tool

and look at the character 1064.

Did you look at the inner exception ? it's often more interesting in the case of a serialization exception.